# How to Use AWS Athena Supported Time zones at_timezone in an incremental query

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I am having an issue where users in different timezones are editing tables but the time they edit them is different from the timezone where the Data is stored.

Currently I have been using the following incremental query

```
SELECT 
some,
table,
columns,
WHERE (date_parse(coalesce(nullif(umv.lastupdated, ''), '2022-01-01 15:01:01'),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') >= date_add('minute', -60, date_parse('[[LASTRUNDATE]]','%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s')))
```

I read on AWS [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/athena-supported-time-zones.html) that there are a few things that can be done but I am new to how Athena handles this.

I imagine it would be something like the following but im not sure and could use the help to become the sql master I wanna believe I am haha.

```
SELECT 
some,
table,
columns,
WHERE AT_TIMEZONE(DATE_PARSE(umv.lastupdated,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'),'America/Detroit') >= AT_TIMEZONE(DATE_PARSE('[[LASTRUNDATE]]','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'),'America/Detroit')
```

Comment: Can you please share some sample data and desired output?

Comment: basically I want whatever timezone the entry happens in, that time always be converted to pacific time